# How to get text inside source code with beautifulsoup

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to do webscraping on this page:

> https://www.nike.com.br/air-max-pre-day-153-169-211-330676

If you look at the source code, and look for the term "Tamanho" (with quotes) you should find something like this below:

```
<script>var SKUsCorTamanho = {"34": {"ProdutoId":"330685", 
"Codigo":"195241995304",
"Tamanho":"34","PrecoDe":"R$ 0,00",
"PrecoPor":"R$ 699,99",
"PrecoPorSemPromocao":"R$ 699,99",
"ValorParcela":"R$ 58,33",  
"ParcelamentoMaximmo:"12","PreVenda":"0","DtLancto":"15\/06\/2021 
}}</script>
```

How could I get only sizes with beautifulsoup?

```
request = request.get("https://www.nike.com.br/air-max-pre-day-153-169-211-330676")
soup = bs4(request.text, "html.parser")
tamanho = soup.find_all(?)
print(tamanho)
//Result I want on script output
Tamanho 34 or 34
```

I need this to return me the size in that json at the beginning of the question for example, how can I do this? How can I do this?

Comment: Why are trying to get info from the script of the page. Surely, you should have tried to get it from the html part right?

Comment: @PCM Yes, but the part that is rendered in the html is dynamic

Comment: I checked the page, I suggest you inspect the buttons for different sizes and try getting the size from there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simplify with less imports. Just use re.findall on response text

```
import requests, re

r = requests.get('https://www.nike.com.br/air-max-pre-day-153-169-211-330676').text
sizes = re.findall(r'"Tamanho":"(.*?)"', r)
```

Answer (score 0):

Find the `<script>` tag as usual and then parse it with `re`. This is not the best method because `re` doesn't understand JS, but should do the job.

```py
import requests, bs4, re

a = requests.get("https://www.nike.com.br/air-max-pre-day-153-169-211-330676")
b = bs4.BeautifulSoup(a.text, "html.parser")
d = next(c.text for c in b.find_all('script') if 'Tamanho' in c.text)

size = list(map(lambda i: re.sub('[^0-9,]', '', i), re.findall(r'"Tamanho":"[^"]*"', d)))
print(size)
```

Output:

```
['34', '34,5', '35', '35,5', '36', '37', '37,5', '38', '39', '39,5', '40', '40,5', '41', '42', '42,5', '43', '43,5', '44', '45', '46', '47', '48']
```

Comment: I'm getting `StopInteration` how to do without for loop?

Comment: Which line did the code break? The code runs fine on my machine.

Comment: Um, `StopIteration` looks like in line 5. Probably check the content in `b`. Do `b.text` look fine?

Comment: In Line 5, but it would be good for me if there wasn't the necessity of a for loop

Comment: There are multiple `Tamanho` in the script (shown above). What do you need? Only the first result?

Comment: I need to get all the sizes, and I'm going to put the code snippet inside a for loop, so I don't want to have to put a for loop inside a for loop, you know?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/234221/discussion-between-dibery-and-gjsks).

Comment: This worked, I only accepted the other answer because it uses fewer imports and has little code line, but I gave a positive vote

Answer (score 0):

this code is tested on Python 3.9

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import re
import json

request = requests.get("https://www.nike.com.br/air-max-pre-day-153-169-211-330676")
soup = BeautifulSoup(request.text, "html.parser")
script = soup.find_all('script')[9].string
script = script[len('var SKUsCorTamanho = '):]
variables = json.loads(script)
Tamanho = variables[list(variables.keys())[0]]['Tamanho']
print ("Tamanho : ", Tamanho)
```

Comment: I would like to say that I need to get the size without needing to know the size beforehand

Comment: I have edited the code for you, now you can iterate through the dictionary if you want